# Mark Occurrences does not work in xtend editor in Eclipse Mars

Tags: xtend, find-occurrences, eclipse-mars

Eclipse behaves strange here. I've updated everything. And "Mark Occurrences" works in a normal Java editor, but it does not in and xtend-editor.

Do you have any information what's the reason for that? Is this a bug?

I've also tried to use the workaround to select something in the outline and switching back to some variable. The workaround doesn't work either.

My Eclipse is running on a Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in Mars. Did you activate it? Unfortunately, it is disabled by default.

[image]